# How to automate visual studio publish and attach debugger?

Tags: automation, macros, visual-studio-2019

In VS2019, How can I automate publish and then attach debugger? We have code which cannot be run without IIS. So any change can be debugged by publish to IIS folder and attach debugger to w3p process. 
I want to automate all this. 
Also, we have to run Visual studio as an administrator in order to attach debugger so automation tools outside like autohotkey don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my Visual Commander extension to automate it as described in the following article https://blog.markvincze.com/attach-to-process-shortcut-in-visual-studio/

Comment: This really helped. I would like to add publish to folder command too. Is there any example of that please?

Comment: @PAS For publish try something like DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.PublishSelection");